# Why absolute units in CSS are not shown really absolute in different screens?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, screen

> The so-called absolute units (**cm**, **mm**, **in**, **pt** and **pc**) mean the same in
>   CSS as everywhere else, *but only if your output device has a high
>   enough resolution.*
>
> source: W3C

when I put the preceding code in my project I expect to see 1cm everywhere...

```
.myColumn{
   width: 1cm;
}
```

W3C says for low-resolution screens, case would not be the same.

Why?

Why cannot they produce **1cm** correctly?

In cell-phones, and tablets and... the only screen unit is **pixel**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS units don't necessarily equate to exact dimensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#CSS_units_and_dots-per-inch). In the end, every CSS measurement displayed on a screen is eventually calculated in pixels.

CSS assumes screens will have 96 dpi, so using in, pt, and pc is usually safe, although different monitor resolutions, or user-defined zooming may affect your results.

Metric units are a different story though, as there is no exact calculation to pixels, so the numbers are rounded by the browser to deliver a result that will be close to the specified measurement. This is one of the reasons that the [W3C only recommends px, %, or em units](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) for screen targeted layouts.